# (emberJS) - TypeError while using find on RESTAdaper JSON data

Tags: json, ember.js

I'm new to emberJS, and try to find out how to put data from JSON API to my model. So I have:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
revision: 12,
adapter : DS.RESTAdapter.create({
 url : 'http://eu.battle.net/api/d3/profile/Alucard-2129/?callback=?'
 }) });

App.Profiles = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr("string"),
lastUpdated: DS.attr("string")});


App.ProfilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function () {        
    return App.Profiles.find();
}});
```

But it does't work at all... I get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function () { ... } has no method 'find'
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ember is kind of new, it changes a lot. If you download the latest Ember build and a copy of the Ember Data beta plugin, you can do it this way:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://eu.battle.net/api/d3/profile/Alucard-2129/?callback=?'
});

App.Profiles = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr("string"),
lastUpdated: DS.attr("string")});

App.ProfilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find("profile");
  }
});
```

All help you find online, is already outdated. At least, that's what I experienced. This page lists a lot of changes that probably will come in handy: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#host-and-namespace-configuration

Good luck ;)

Comment: Unfortunatelly I get error like this: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeKey' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

Probally you are using the ember-data version `1.0.0-beta`. And your code is from the older version. Now instead of `App.Profiles.find();` you need to use `store.find('profiles');`.

The full description of the transition from the older version to the 1.0.0-beta is described [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md)

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://eu.battle.net/api/d3/profile/Alucard-2129/?callback=?'
});

App.Profiles = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr("string"),
  lastUpdated: DS.attr("string")
});

App.ProfilesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find("profiles");
  }
});
```

I hope it helps